# HTML canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an index.hTML file that just renders a canvas like this

```
<body>
    <canvas>
    </canvas>
    <script src="./JS/index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

I have a single javascript file that I'm using to manipulate the canvas as below

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

class Circle {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color){
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
    }

    draw(){
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, Math.PI*2, false)
        c.strokeStyle = this.color

        c.stroke()

    }

}
 function manyCircles (numberOfCircles){
     requestAnimationFrame(manyCircles)
     c.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth, innerHeight)
     for (let i = 0; i <numberOfCircles; i++) {
        let x = Math.random()*innerWidth
        let y = Math.random() * innerHeight
        const circ1 = new Circle(x, y, 50, 'blue')
        circ1.draw()
     }   
     debugger
 }

manyCircles(5)
```

the goal here is to have 5 circles drawn on the canvas at random coordinates each time the function runs and to be cleared and the cycle to repeat but apparently the for loop runs forever and just fills the screen with circles. 
However if I have it like this

```
 function manyCircles (){
     requestAnimationFrame(manyCircles)
     c.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth, innerHeight)
     for (let i = 0; i <5; i++) {
        let x = Math.random()*innerWidth
        let y = Math.random() * innerHeight
        const circ1 = new Circle(x, y, 50, 'blue')
        circ1.draw()
     }   
     debugger
 }

manyCircles()
```

it seems to work
Can somebody tell me why it works the second case but not the first? what principle i'm i missing here

Comment: `numberOfCircles` is the timestamp passed to the [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Syntax), it's quite a big number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass arguments inside `requestAnimationFrame`, you need to do it inside a function.

By default the argument passed to the callback function inside `raf` is the timestamp. As pointed out in the comments, it is an increasingly huge number.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.radius = radius
    this.color = color
  }

  draw() {
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, Math.PI * 2, false)
    c.strokeStyle = this.color

    c.stroke()

  }

}

function manyCircles(numberOfCircles) {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    manyCircles(numberOfCircles)
  })
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++) {
    let x = Math.random() * innerWidth
    let y = Math.random() * innerHeight
    const circ1 = new Circle(x, y, 50, 'blue')
    circ1.draw()
  }
  debugger
}

manyCircles(5)
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```